# Оптимизация алгоритма с циклами

Tags: java

Как можно упростить/оптимизировать данный алгоритм?

Это класс, на вход поступает массив. Сейчас в нем только 7 значений. А если значений очень много то он работает медленно. Как ускорить его работу?

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = new int[7];
        A[0] = 4;
        A[1] = 6;
        A[2] = 2;
        A[3] = 2;
        A[4] = 6;
        A[5] = 6;
        A[6] = 1;
        System.out.println(solution(A));
    }
    static int solution(int[] A) {
        int result = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (int X : A) {
            i++;
            int j = 0;
            for (int Y : A) {
                j++;
                if (X == Y)
                    result = Math.max(result, Math.abs(i - j));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

выводит результат 4.

Comment: Сейчас сложность `O(n^2)`, да в общем то это и минимум для этого алгоритма. Можно только сделать `break` в циклах после находки необходимого.

Comment: спасибо, я правда еще IntStream.range(0, N).forEach(i -> {... сделал, но тоже не помогло))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот со стримами, работает шустро:

```
private static int solution2(int...a) {
  class Point {
    int index, value;
    Point(int index, int value) {
      this.index = index;
      this.value = value;
    }
    public int getIndex() { return index; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
  }

  return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Point(i, a[i]))
    .collect(groupingBy(Point::getValue, mapping(Point::getIndex, toList())))
    .values().stream()
    .mapToInt(list -> list.get(list.size() - 1) - list.get(0))
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
    .findFirst().get();
}
```